# Are there any active, regularly scheduled commercial flights that are reserved for only one gender or other demographic factor?

Tags: air-travel, discrimination

I read on https://viewfromthewing.com/united-airlines-men-only-executive-service/ ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20200424120350/https://viewfromthewing.com/united-airlines-men-only-executive-service/)):

> From 1953 through 1970, United offered men-only ‘Executive flights’ between New York and Chicago and between Los Angeles and San Francisco.
>
> These flights were operated by DC-6B aircraft and later Caravelles. Flights mostly operated at 5pm in each direction between the two cities (generally six days a week excluding Saturdays). They didn’t just ban women, but children also, and flight attendants catered to these business flights with special meals and offered complimentary cigars.

Are there any active, regularly scheduled commercial flights that are reserved for only one gender or other demographic factor?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/141562/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-are-there-any-active-regularly-sch).